# Netty 5 channel shared by multiple threads shows very poor performance

Tags: java, sockets, netty, nio

I have a netty implementation, client/server, where many threads are sharing a single channel with a SimpleChannelInboundHandler.

The messages per second (TPS) for our implementation will be very high 1000+. Each message sends a java object (TransactionBundle) and uses messageReceived() to read back the response from the server)

The sent message, sent in the send() method, is stored in a ConcurrentHashMap in the Handler accessed by a unique key, and the response from messageReceived() uses this key to look up the original sent message to remove the object from the 
ConcurrentHashMap and complete the process.

In the send() method we use a FutureTask to wait for the associated response to return from the server via messageReceived. When it returns the response notifies this FutureTask to complete.

The problem is that as the number of messages increase the response time is constantly increasing until we start seeing FutureTask time-outs (at 60 seconds) in the SimpleChannelInboundHandler.send().

I've previously added a ChannelFutureListener to the writeAndFlush and have found that the write takes longer and longer to send, it's not instantaneous unless it's under low load. Based on timings I've taken it feels like the server cannot 
handle the write load.

It's as though the channel is unable to handle the load we're sending to it. Interestingly the response from the server is very quick, only sends are affected from what I can tell.

I'm thinking increasing buffer sizes etc. I've included relevant Client code below.

The channel is created as:

```
public ClientConnection(String host, String port, EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup) throws SSLException, InterruptedException {

    HOST = System.getProperty("host", host);
    PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", port));

    SslContext sslCtx;
    if (SSL) {
        sslCtx = SslContext.newClientContext(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE);
    } else {
        sslCtx = null;
    }

    this.eventLoopGroup = eventLoopGroup;

    // Make the connection attempt.
    future = getBootStrap(sslCtx).connect(HOST, PORT).sync();

    InetSocketAddress socket = (InetSocketAddress) future.channel().remoteAddress();
    verifiedRemoteHost = socket.getHostString();
    verfiedRemotePort = socket.getPort();

    handler = (ClientConnectionHandler) future.channel().pipeline().last();

}

private Bootstrap getBootStrap(final SslContext sslCtx) {

    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(eventLoopGroup)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                    if (sslCtx != null) {
                        p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), HOST, PORT));
                    }
                    p.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
                    p.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
                    p.addLast(new ClientConnectionHandler());
                }
            });

    return b;

}
```

The SimpleChannelInboundHandler.send() method is:

```
    public TransactionBundle send(Hashtable bundleIn) {

    //TransactionBundle is a HashMap

    TransactionBundle bundleOut;
    String registryId = getUniqueKey();

    bundleIn.put(CLIENT_REGISTRY_ID, registryId);
    registry.put(registryId, getRegistryItem());

    ctx.writeAndFlush(bundleIn);        //Adding a listener here indicated that the write was progressively getting slower

    logger.trace("Sent transaction for registryId [{}]", registryId);

    try {

        registry.get(registryId).getFutureTask().get(FUTURE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  //time-outs occur here

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException ex) {
        logger.error("FutureTask Failed [{}] for registryId [{}]", ex.getMessage(), registryId, ex);
    }

    logger.trace("FutureTask completed for registryId [{}]", registryId);

    ....other tasks

    return bundleOut;
}
```

The SimpleChannelInboundHandler.messageReceived() method is:

```
    @Override
protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext chc, Hashtable bundle) throws Exception {

    String registryId = (String) bundle.get(CLIENT_REGISTRY_ID);

    logger.trace("Received message for registry ID [{}]", registryId);
    ClientConnectionRegistryItem registryItem = registry.get(registryId);

    if (registryItem != null) {

        //FutureTask is still waiting for a response
        FutureTask futureTask = registryItem.getFutureTask();

        if (futureTask != null) {

            if (!futureTask.isDone()) {

                //FutureTask is not completed so is ready to receive the response. Add the bundle to the ClientConnectionRegistryItem
                registryItem.setBundle(bundle);
                logger.trace("Registry ID [{}] bundle set", registryId);

            } else {
                //FutureTask has completed already. Log the details
                logger.trace("Registry ID [{}] timeout.", registryId);
            }
            futureTaskExecutor.execute(futureTask);
        }
    } else {
        //Message response with no matching registryId
        //Orphaned transaction should be cleaned up with the timeout of the FutureTask
        logger.error("Registry ID [{}] not found in registry.", registryId);
    }
}
```